# Stop icon shaking while hover using css

Tags: html, css

I set the background color when hovering the Icon.

My HTML element

```
<span class="ion-qr-scanner Expand-img"></span>
```

My CSS

```
.Expand-img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: -2px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.Expand-img:hover{
    background: #468483;
    padding: 0px 3px;   
}
```

Now How I can stop shaking... Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the padding on the hover state onto the .Expand-img class:

```
.Expand-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: -2px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px 3px;  
}

.Expand-img:hover {
    background: #468483; 
}
```

The hover state will inherit it from the parent, therefore stopping the shaking issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with `padding: 0px 3px;` which causes shaking effect.